# react-native-camera: Android app crashing without error

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera

I've added react-native-camera to my application. After creating a component that uses RNCamera, everytime I try to run my app (using `react-native run-android`), it asks for the necessary permissions (camera and audio) and then immediately crashes without outputting any error messages.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@tensorflow-models/mobilenet": "^2.0.4",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^3.3.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.5.0",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-camera": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "^10.0.1",
    "expo-gl": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-gl-cpp": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.8.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-updates": "~0.4.0",
    "mobx": "^6.1.8",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.43.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.12.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven")
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://www.jitpack.io'
        }



        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is my /app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false
]

apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/expo-constants/scripts/get-app-config-android.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/create-manifest-android.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion "22.0.7026061"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chowtime"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'mlkit'
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.7.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    
    implementation (project(':react-native-camera')) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms", module: "play-services-vision"
        exclude group: "com.google.firebase", module: "firebase-ml-vision-face-model"
    }

    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:19.0.3") {
        force = true;
    }
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2") {
        force = true;
    }

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }
    addUnimodulesDependencies()

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

EDIT:
This is what my AndroidManifest.xml looks like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.chowtime">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/@jjwilkin/test_bare"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="40.0.0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="ocr, text" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

This is what my android project directory looks like:

[image]

Any info about why this may be happening or how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

UPDATE: I've tried using expo-camera in the same repo (I read that react-native-camera is built on expo-camera), and that works fine.

EDIT: This is the output from running `adb logcat`: pastebin.com/yWM5Mat8.

Comment: Can you include the output of `adb logcat` when causing the crash? That may provide some better hints.

Comment: The output from running that command is quite long. Is there a specific section I should be looking at?

Comment: I would run it in a terminal while you have the app open and then look for something that looks like a java stacktrace when the app crashes. If you're having hard time identifying that I would put the whole output into pastebin and link it here.

Comment: I've tried looking through it and haven't made any progress. I'd really appreciate your help: https://pastebin.com/yWM5Mat8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging through the pastepin, this appears to be the culprit:

```
03-31 21:51:16.152 13039 13039 E unknown:ViewManager: Error while updating prop playSoundOnCapture
03-31 21:51:16.152 13039 13039 E unknown:ViewManager: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
... a bunch of traceback lines
03-31 21:51:16.152 13039 13039 E unknown:ViewManager: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setPlaySoundOnCapture(Z)V in class Lorg/reactnative/camera/RNCameraView; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.reactnative.camera.RNCameraView' appears in /data/app/~~2TIdBhLTuyzCkV7CYFT2Mg==/com.chowtime-uS9KR34-elnZ0EmL_ovT3w==/base.apk!classes4.dex)
```

This github issue may be relevant: https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/issues/2938#issuecomment-671436341 It doesn't appear to have a good resolution but suggests that the conflict happens if both react-native-camera and expo-camera are installed as it appears they are in your package.json. You may need to choose one or the other if they depend on different versions of `com.google.android.cameraview.CameraView`.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

Add above the camera permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file. After check once.

Comment: I've already added that. I've edited my question to include my AndroidManifest.xml file